# Passing objects attributes to multiple text fields on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have some html/angular:

```
                            <td class="col-md-4" colspan="4">
                                <label class="control-label ">{{item.fields[1].displayName}}11</label>
                                <div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="item[item.fields[1].name]" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxGPIOptions(2, 70, item[item.fields[1].name], 'searchGpi')" />
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
                                        <li data-ng-repeat="name in searchGpi" style="width:100%"><a data-ng-click="changeData(item.fields[1].name, name);"><span class="GpiId">{{name}}</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <label class="error" data-ng-show="issueSuppNum()">Please insert a valid GPI #.</label>
                                </td>
                            <td class="col-md-3" colspan="4">
                                <label class="control-label">{{item.fields[11].displayName}}22</label>
                                <div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="GENERIC_NAME" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxGenOptions(2, 148, item[item.fields[11].name], 'searchGenericOptions')" />
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
                                        <li data-ng-repeat="name in searchGenericOptions" style="width:100%"><a data-ng-click="changeData('GENERIC_NAME', name)"><span class="GenId">{{name}}</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <label class="error" data-ng-show="issueSuppNum()">Please insert a valid generic name.</label>
                                @*<div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="formReadOnly" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(item.fields[7].htmlName)" data-strat-model="item" data-field="item.fields[7]"></div>*@
                            </td>
```

Notice: `data-ng-click="changeData(item.fields[1].name, name);"`

When this function fires I want 2 different fields to change text to an object coming in:

Here it is:

```
    $scope.changeData = function (propertyName, name) {
        $scope.item[propertyName] = name;
        jQuery('.GpiId').text(name.GPI);
        jQuery('.GenId').text(name.GENERIC_NAME);
    };
```

If  I check the object name passing through it is an object with 2 values:

[image]

I want to either send those 2 fields back through to the view or change the values with jQuery. I believe the reason only name.GPI goes through is because

```
    $scope.changeData = function (propertyName, name) {
        $scope.item[propertyName] = name.GPI;
        jQuery('.GenId').text(name.GENERIC_NAME);
        jQuery('.TherId').text(name.THER_CLASS_DESC);
```

There is a span class in the HTML around the text I want to change:

```
<span class="GenId">{{name}}</span>
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: As previously mentioned in another post you need to completely re-think how you do things using angular. Your data model should drive the view...not dom manipulation using jQuery. Create a demo that reproduces your issue. The deeper you get into project working this way the more headaches you will run into

Comment: And get used to passing whole objects in functions in view....will find it much easier to work with in controller

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah I want to but I have a deadline and it just needs to be done right now. I am planning on changing it in the future when I have time. Also, how would I send those values to the through to the view instead of using jquery?

Comment: By assigning them to model properties so that they get compiled and printed inside your `{{}}`. To be very honest i don't understand your issue here , thus a request for a [mcve]